# Nginx reverse proxy is not sending my http requests to server running on localhost (POST/GET)

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm running a node express server on an ec2 instance (ec2-13-229-218-180.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com). It is running a web server that handles http POST requests that will interact with an RDS database, returning queries.

My goal is to have POST/GET requests to the endpoints for example  (ec2-13-229-218-180.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/getData), and have nginx understand and translate that to a POST/GET request to http://localhost:3000/getData)

From my understanding, I have to setup the nginx configuration like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ec2-13-229-218-180.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {

            proxy_server http://localhost:3000;                                                    
            //other stuff
    }
```

}

Nginx is able to run with the current configuration, but when I try to test sending post requests to ec2-13-229-218-180.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/getData , i'm getting 404's. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code snippet outside the server block

```
    upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Then replace

```
proxy_server http://localhost:3000;
```

by

```
proxy_pass       http://nodejs;
```